# .htaccess redirect based on query string, preserve string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect one URL to another if a specific value (do=login) only if a value in the query string is matched. I'd like to preserve the whole string as it forwards to the another domain/url.

For example:

- If a visitor hits https://domain1.com/myscript/script1.php?do=login&why=because the rule will match (do=login is found) and the URL is rewritten to https://domain2.com/script1.php?do=login&why=because
- If a visitor hits https://domain1.com/myscript/script1.php?why=because the rule will not match (do=login is not found) and the URL will not be rewritten. It will remain https://domain1.com/myscript/script1.php?why=because

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't appear to be working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =domain1.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (do=login)
RewriteRule ^$ https://domain2.com/script1.php/?%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,L]
```

I don't have much experience with rewrite rules and have been trying to get this to work for hours. Any help you can offer is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not working because your current `RewriteRule` only matches root page `/`. You need to match `myscript/script1.php`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} do=login [NC]
RewriteRule ^myscript/script1\.php$ https://domain2.com/script1.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to validate the answer in order to mark your question as solved